# Thinktecture Identity Server and ASP.NET Open OAuth

Tags: asp.net, oauth

Anyone succeeded to use Thinktecture Identity Server as an OAuth identity provider for ASP.NET Open OAuth?

I would like to use the Identity Server as an OAuth Identity provider (similar to Google and Facebook) from a simple ASP.Net MVC application.
Is it supported?

Thanks

Manu

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the GitHub project page for [Identity Server version 1](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v1/) or the GitHub project page for  [Identity Server version 2](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/)?